# numpy indexing with an array of index (to be broadcasted)

Tags: numpy, indexing

Let `A` be an array of shape `(n_0, n_1, …, n_p-2, n_p-1)` with arbitrary `p`.

Let `ind` be and array of shape `(m_0, m_1, …, m_p-2, m_p-1)`, with, for all `k`:

- either `m_k == n_k`
- or `m_k == 1`.

The values of `ind` are indices corresponding to the p-th axis of `A`, namely integers in `{0, 1, …, p-1}`.

I want to get an array `B` of shape `(n_0, n_1, …, n_p-1)` such that
`B[i_0, i_1, …, i_p-2, i_p-1]` equals
`A[i_0, i_1, …, i_p-2, ind[j_0, j_1, …, j_p-2, j_p-1]` with, for all `k`:

- `j_k == i_k` if `m_k == n_k`,
- or `j_k == 0` if `m_k == 1`.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I ended writing the following (not thoroughly tested) function. I suppose (hope) better performances are achievable

```
def time_shift(signal, index_shifted):
    """Time shift an array of signal with shifted (time) indices.

    Time is indexed by the last dimension.

    Args:
       signal (array): original signals.
       index_shifted (array): shifted indices, with same shape as signal, or
           possibly 1 along dimension to be broadcasted.

    Returns:
        Array with shifted values.
    """

    out = np.empty(np.shape(signal))
    it = np.nditer([index_shifted, out], flags=['multi_index'],
                   op_flags = [['readonly'],
                               ['writeonly', 'allocate', 'no_broadcast']])
    with it:
        for ind, zz in it:
            selection = (*it.multi_index[:-1], ind)
            zz[...] = signal[selection]
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest solution I could come up with after some testing. The idea is: broadcast `ind` matrix so that it has the same shape as `A`, then use the fact that the `ind` matrix has the same values accros axes which were expanded by broadcasting (i. e. there's no need to iterate over these axes).

If the shape of `ind` matrix is the same as the shape of `A` my function works actually slower, but with one or more dimensions of `ind` set to 1, this function works substantially faster.

Note that this is "logical" optimalization. I believe it's possible to make it faster by maybe using some other `numpy` functions, different handling of list and tuples etc.

The function:

```py
import numpy as np
import time
from itertools import product

def time_shift_opt(signal, index_shifted):

  index_broadcasted = np.broadcast_to(index_shifted, signal.shape)
  out = np.empty(np.shape(signal))

  indices = product(*[range(d) for d in index_shifted.shape])

  dims_to_expand = [i for i, val in enumerate(index_shifted.shape) if val == 1]

  for index in indices:
    index_to_change = list(index)
    for d in dims_to_expand:
      index_to_change[d] = slice(None)

    index_to_change = tuple(index_to_change)

    val_index = list(index_to_change)
    val_index[-1] = index_broadcasted[index]
    value = signal[tuple(val_index)]

    if index_shifted.shape[-1] == 1:
      value = value[..., np.newaxis]

    out[index_to_change] = value

  return out
```

Comparing times: (See that with the growing number of `ind` dimensions set to 1 the function I proposed runs much faster)

```py
def test_time_optimality(signal_shape, ind_shape, n_iterations = 10):
  p = signal_shape[-1]
  A = np.random.randint(1000, size = size)
  ind = np.random.randint(p, size = ind_size)

  averages = []

  temp_average = 0
  for i in range(n_iterations):
    start = time.time()
    res = time_shift(A, ind)
    temp_average += time.time() - start

  averages.append(temp_average/n_iterations)

  temp_average = 0
  for i in range(n_iterations):
    start = time.time()
    res = time_shift_opt(A, ind)
    temp_average += time.time() - start

  averages.append(temp_average/n_iterations)

  print('time_shift average duration: {:.4f}'.format(averages[0]))
  print('time_shift_opt average duration: {:.4f}'.format(averages[1]))

p = 3
size = (10, 20, 12, 50, p)
ind_size = (10, 20, 12, 50, p)
test_time_optimality(size, ind_size)
# time_shift average duration: 0.3734
# time_shift_opt average duration: 0.5365

size = (10, 20, 12, 50, p)
ind_size = (10, 1, 12, 50, p)
test_time_optimality(size, ind_size)
# time_shift average duration: 0.3697
# time_shift_opt average duration: 0.0414

size = (10, 20, 12, 50, p)
ind_size = (1, 1, 12, 50, p)
test_time_optimality(size, ind_size)
# time_shift average duration: 0.3840
# time_shift_opt average duration: 0.0080

size = (10, 20, 12, 50, p)
ind_size = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
test_time_optimality(size, ind_size)

# time_shift average duration: 0.3775
# time_shift_opt average duration: 0.0018
```